# iOS/Swift : Firebase dynamic Link parse issue

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I am working on firebase dynamic link project. The dynamic link gets generated properly. Also works well when opened in android application. But when i tried to open in iOS app, App gets open only. Prameter value from that link doesn't get parsed and recovered. I got error like '[connection] nw_read_request_report [C10] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"'.  I found same question, none of them has working solution suggested . How to parse parameters from universal link(Dynamic Link)?

[connection] nw_read_request_report [C10] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"

Comment: You will get much more responses if you add some part of your implementation or probably the generated dynamic link in your case. As for now, I would suggest you put `d=1` at the end of your dynamic link and open link in a browser to generate a debug flowchart to find issues if any. For example: **example.page.link/suffix?d=1**